# Extracting <span /> part of html node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a line that is part of the `html` returned:

```
<h1 id="pgName" class="floatLVal tight">IBM Dividend Yield (TTM):</h1><span id="pgNameVal">3.74% for May 31, 2017</span>
```

that I read as follows. I see the node, but I can't see any of the text past `(TTM):` in any of the `singleNode` fields, e.g, as part of `innerhtml`. I would like to extract the "3.74% for May 31, 2017" part.

**What is the correct way to extract this information?**

```
HtmlDocument document = ... 
var singleNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='floatLVal tight']");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` tag is not located in `h1` tag. Either get next sibling node of `h1`

```
var h1 = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='floatLVal tight']");
var span = h1.NextSibling;
var text = span.InnerHtml; // "3.74% for May 31, 2017"
```

Or get `span` node by id:

```
var span = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='pgNameVal']");
var text = span.InnerHtml; // "3.74% for May 31, 2017"
```